# How to Implement default Windows buttons to a Tkinter program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

why doesn't my python program have default windows 7/8/xp buttons but rather dull windows 2000 buttons? How can I fix this?

**My dull buttoned program**

[image: my dull program]

**What I expect :**

[image: cool buttons]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ttk` module for those effects:

```
import Tkinter
import ttk
root = Tkinter.Tk()
ttk.Button(text="Hello").grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Example:

[image: demo window]